# How does User Custom Field Value work in Jira Notification scheme

Tags: jira

I am new to Jira and I have issue when some of the users are not getting email notification when someone tags them in a comment of the story.
My suggestion is to create outlook group and then I can add that as group in Notification scheme.
Along with that I would like to know how User Custom field value and Group custom field value works.

Any information along these lines is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

About notifications:

- add your users to jira, and set emails
- create your groups (or roles) depending on what make more sense.
- Then add users to groups
- go to Admin>issues>notifications schemes> : create your scheme
- Set notifications to your scheme, adding people to each event
- There is a notification called "issue commented" or something similar.
- Click add. Select Group(or role), and set wich group should be notificated

About the mentions, it is automatic, but you have to ensure your users are in the jira users directory and not only in a MActive Directory or whatever (if i remember ok):
http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/06/using-watchers-and-mentions-effectively/

> Say you and a coworker both discover the same issue; obviously, only one of you should file it. In the description you can quickly use an @mention to loop your colleague in on the issue. When you submit the issue to JIRA, they will get one notification that the issue was filed. That way, they don’t file the issue thinking that you didn’t. The benefit of using an @mention over adding them as a watcher is that they only get notified once.

About this question :"Along with that I would like to know how User Custom field value and Group custom field value works."

They works really similar to usual users and groups. What's your problem with them exactly.

Regards,